# Upgrade parse server 2.x to 3.x is the old code base compatible

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

Can we update parse server 2.8 to 3.x. Our cloud code base is using backbone style reponse callbacks. Is this compatible with the new 3.x update. Specifically 3.1.2.

Our code base uses the old style success, error callbacks do we have to migrate all our code to promises or async wait as per the changelong

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Parse-server version 3 and above, Parse Server is using the Parse JS SDK version 2.0+.

So, you need to change all backbone styles to either:

- Promises
- Async/Await functions

for instance:

```js
new Parse.Query('your_class_name')
.find({
 success:function(result){}
});
```

should change to:

```js
new Parse.Query('your_class_name')
.find()
.then((results)=>{})
.catch((error)=>{})
```

If you are inside of an async function, then you can do:

```js
const asyncFunc = async() => {

  try {
    const results = await new Parse.Query('your_class_name').find();
    // do something with the results here.

  } catch (error) {
    // do something with the error
  }

}
```

Comment: Isn't there an `await` missing after `const results =`?

Answer (score 0):

After having a direct conversation with one of the repo contributors the code has to migrated see the [migration guide](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/3.0.0.md)